# Complexity analysis of logarithms

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, logarithm

I have two functions, f(n)=log<sub>2</sub>n and g(n)=log<sub>10</sub>n. I am trying to decide whether f(n) is O(g(n)), or Ω(g(n)) or Θ(g(n)). I thinks i should take the limit f(n)/g(n) as n goes to infinity, and I think that limit is constant so f(n) must be Θ(n).

Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

log<sub>2</sub>n = log<sub>10</sub>n / log<sub>10</sub>2 (from [here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/logrules5.htm))

So f(n) = g(n) / log<sub>10</sub>2

So f(n) and g(n) only differ by a constant factor (since log<sub>10</sub>2 is constant).

So, from [the definitions of O(x), Ω(x) and Θ(x)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations), I'd say:

f(n) ∈ O(g(n)),
f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n)),
f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n))

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. From complexity point of view (at least big O point of view) doesn't matter if it is log<sub>2</sub> or log<sub>10</sub>.

f(n) is both O(g(n)) and f(n) is Ω(g(n)), f(n) is Θ(g(n))

Answer (score 1):

As the limit is constant, you are right that f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)) (assuming you have a typo in the question). Also of course g(n) ∈ Θ(f(n)).

BTW: Not only the limit of the ratio is constant but log<sub>2</sub>n/log<sub>10</sub>n is always a constant(log<sub>2</sub>10).